# Can't setup Thunderbird to read Outlook mail accounts

Tags: email, thunderbird, office-for-mac

I consider myself geeky yet my soul is burning over a fairly simple problem.

I need to set-up a number of email accounts on my computer. I have a remote POSTFIX/Courier server which is able to sent/receive emails to/from Outlook 2011 Mac.

Now I've decided to open a couple of new accounts on the server and add them to a Thunderbird client so that I can separate them from the rest of my accounts in Outlook. I read about profiles but it wasn't very helpful. Anyway, I would like to use Thunderbird on these new accounts.

Here are my settings that work fine in OUTLOOK but I can't sort them out in TB

in: mail.example.com
out: mail.example.com
user: test@example.com
pass: ...
require (SPA)

Advance
in: 995/SSL
out: 587/TLS

I think it is something to do with the authentication methods.

So these are the settings that work with outlook, and for the past few hours give me hard time on TB. I also tried to use Mac's Mail which failed too...

I get errors like:
Wrong password (no idea why)
Server settings are wrong ... Nothing that can point me in any direction.

Any suggestion as to how to configure the application, would be much appreciated.

Here is a screen of the settings that work in Outlook 2011 Mac
http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/4647/probreo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should first check your server's mail logs (usually /var/log/mail.info). It should give you a useful authentication error. Since you're presumably using courier-imap, you should enable debug logging by setting "DEBUG_LOGIN=1" in your authdaemonrc. This will give you even more useful information on why you can't authenticate.

Comment: I'm using POP3 on the server, and I'm not totally familiar with troubleshooting a linux machine for that matter. Is there a way to just use these settings as in Outlook?